# Perform a 'protected abstract override' for an abstract class which implements a generic interface

Tags: c#

I have an interface which looks like this:

```
public interface ISomeInterface<out TEntityA, TEntityB> 
    where TEntityA : ISomeEntityA
    where TEntityB : ISomeEntityB
{
    TEntityA SomeMethod(TEntityB entityB);
}
```

On the other hand, I have a abstract class which implements this interface, so, using the intellisense the implementation looks this way:

```
public abstract class BaseAbstractClass : ISomeInterface<EntityA, EntityB>
{
    public EntityA SomeMethod(EntityB entityB)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Since **EntityA** and **EntityB** are both concrete implementations of **ISomeEntityA** and **ISomeEntityB** respectively, it seems that I'm forced to throw a *NotImplementedException* and this looks pretty dirty.

Being that you can't change the signature when you override a method, my question is: **"Is there a way to perform a 'protected abstract override' in order to force the implementation of *SomeMethod* in the inherited classes of *BaseAbstractClass*?"**

For more clarity, I want to do is something like this **(It won't compile)**:

```
public abstract class BaseAbstractClass : ISomeInterface<EntityA, EntityB>
{
    public abstract override EntityA SomeMethod(EntityB entityB);
}
```

Comment: interface implementations can only be public or private.

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. Why do you need to throw a `NotImplementedException`? Why don't you simply make this method abstract? `public abstract EntityA SomeMethod(EntityB entityB);`

Comment: Interfaces define the **public** interface to a class, so you can't use an interface to define `protected` members.

Comment: @DanielA.White How do you define a private member in an interface?

Comment: @RonBeyer updated comment to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply get rid of the `override`. This will compile:

```
public abstract class BaseAbstractClass : ISomeInterface<EntityA, EntityB>
{
    public abstract EntityA SomeMethod(EntityB entityB);
}
```

It's called an "abstract interface implementation".

Comment: That was what I needed!! Thank you Daniel!! Now I need to set the 'override' keyword on the inherited classes instead of BaseAbstractClass. I didn't knew about this concept.

Comment: @MauroBilotti just a heads up that this is not a protected method.

Comment: Yes Daniel, you're right... this is not possible because the interface sets the method as public, isn't it? Anyway, it solved my problem because I will call this method directly from the concrete class.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you call it something else?

```
public abstract class BaseAbstractClass : ISomeInterface<EntityA, EntityB>
{
    protected abstract EntityA SomeMethodImpl(EntityB entityB);

    public EntityA SomeMethod(EntityB entityB) 
    {
        return SomeMethodImpl(entityB);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why take this detour at all? See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679928/perform-a-protected-abstract-override-for-an-abstract-class-which-implements-a#comment51301602_31679928).

Comment: Because SomeMethod is located in a different assembly... I forgot to say that. I need to implement the interface in the BaseAbstractClass.

Comment: @MauroBilotti you can't not implement and implement at the same time.

Comment: It might be the only solution... your answer help me.

Comment: Thanks Dan for you too, but the other Daniel gave me what I needed. I have upvote you! I didn't knew the concept of "abstract interface implementation".